# How to refs on class attribute

Tags: sencha-touch

I build an app for file system. Files from root directory will be load initially. After user taps a directory subfiles should be load and so on. Here is a problem: I dont know
how deep users file structure is.
Means I dont know how many views I will need.
Currently I want to make it this way(But I am happy for ideas to improve my app): User taps on a file. The controller should catch the tap event and should create a new View where loaded data should be placed in.

Thats the theory.

In praxis all my file views has a class. Lets call it 'fileStructureView'. And I have only one Controller for x-number of fileStructureViews.
In my contollers config I made it this way:

Code:

```
config: {
  refs : {
    fileStructureViews : 'list[class="fileStructureView"]'
  },
  control : {
    fileStructureViews  : {
      onItem : 'onItem'
    }
  }
},

onItem : function() {
   alert('Test');
}
```

In my view I set a handler on the items which fires an onItem event.

But my onItem Event will never executed.

If I choose view-ids in the refs it works, but because I have to create an unknown number of views I have to give classes to my views.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest You to use routing in controller and dynamically create views. For example go to to sencha sdk and find project Touch Style.

Hope this helps